# Meaning and etymology of "kemosabe"

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've heard it recently in a movie called " Lone Ranger". Tonto called the lone ranger kemosabe. What does it mean and what is the origin?

Comment: Some interesting suggestions available on line.

Comment: There is just to much complication. Couldn't find a reliable source. Every site is saying something different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2013/06/26/kemosabe_meaning_origin_and_history_of_tonto_s_word_in_lone_ranger.html) in Slate states:

> The phrase has stumped scholars and *Lone Ranger* fans alike for
>   years, and there appears to be no conclusive evidence as to its true
>   definition or its roots.

However, [another site](http://spot.colorado.edu/~koontz/faq/etymology.htm) (written by a specialist in Siouan languages) asserts:

> The word Kemosabe is from an Algonquian language similar to Ojibwe (a
>   complex of related dialects extending from the northern Plains across
>   the Great Lakes into Eastern Canada).
>   ...
>
> The word in question has been explained as 'scout' or 'spy' or even
>   'masked man'.  In the Odawa or Ottawa dialect of Ojibwe the word has
>   the form giimoozaabi.  (Doubled vowels are longer.)  Giimoozaabi is an
>   independent mode third person singular verb meaning 'he looks in
>   secret'.  In Ojibwe a verb form like this like this can be used as a
>   noun, too, so the gloss 'he who looks in secret, a secret looker' is
>   also appropriate.

[The site](http://spot.colorado.edu/~koontz/faq/etymology.htm) provides fairly lengthy discussion that's worth a read.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I always just thought both names were taken from Spanish. "Tonto" meaning "Stupid" and "Quien No Sabe" meaning "He Who Doesn't Know".

Comment: @TJY The correct translation of 'he who doesn't know' in Spanish is 'El que no sabe'.  But this doesn't mean it wasn't a naive Spanglish translation.